# How to use DataProvider with a lot objects (TestNG)

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

could you please help me with my problem.

I am running testNG UT. Code **dataProvider** is:

```
@DataProvider(name = "inputData")
    private Object[][] createInputData() {

        return new Object[][] {
            {new Object1 (1, "string", "string", ObjectX, false), Object2, Object3, false, 3},
            {new Object1 (1, "string", "string", ObjectX, true), Object2, Object3, false, 2},
            {new Object1 (1, "string", "string", ObjectX, false), Object2, Object3, false, 35}
        };
    }
```

**Code of the test:**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "inputData")
    public void test(final Object1 o1, final Object2 o2, final Object3 o3, final boolean b, final int i) {
...
}
```

When I am trying to run it I am receiving exception:

```
test(...)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't invoke method public void (...) on this instance of class ...TestClass_$$_jvste22_0 due to class mismatch
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:73)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:696)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:882)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1189)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Could you please advise me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What version of TestNG are you working with ? Can you please help add that information ? The latest version is `6.12` and is available in [JCenter](https://bintray.com/cbeust/maven/testng/6.12)

Comment: @liotur Is your `createInputData()` and `test` method in different classes?